# Selecting nested forControl in the typescript

Tags: angular

I have a form group like this

```
this.orderForm = this._formBuilder.group({      
  vlanFormGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
    vId: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.positiveInteger)]],
    vName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.vlanNamePattern)]],
    addVToTrunk: [''],
    trunkInterfaces: this._formBuilder.array([
      this.createAddVlanToTrunkMember()
    ])
  })
});
```

I am trying to get vId like this

```
let vId = component.orderForm['vlanFormGroup'].controls['vId'];
```

But it is not working. Please need some help here.

Comment: Can you do a stackblitz?

Comment: Did the answers solve it @raju?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it with FormGroup.get function that takes a string path through nested form elements to the control:

```
this.orderForm.get('vlanFormGroup.vId');
```

Assuming html something like:

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
   <div formGroupName="vlanFormGroup">
      <input type="text" name="id" formControlName="vId">
   </div>
</form>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzt3pv)

Just wondering why you have let vId = **component**.orderForm instead of **this**.orderForm?

Issue with this.orderForm.controls['vlanFormGroup'] is it returns an AbstractControl which doesn't have controls property.

It could be cast to a FormGroup so that the property could be accessed but obviously not as concise as using get function:

```
let vForm = this.orderForm.controls['vlanFormGroup'] as FormGroup;
console.log(vForm.controls['vId']);
```

Note it also needs to be:

```
this.orderForm.controls['vlanFormGroup']
```

instead of:

```
this.orderForm['vlanFormGroup']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
let vId = this.orderForm.get('vlanFormGroup').get('vId')
```